# DC New product not showing in 'all product'

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-commerce

I'm not sure this is the right place to ask the question but I tried everywhere (drupal.exchange drupal etc ... nobodies seems to have seen it)

So I'm trying here. Not I'm happy to investigate myself but as I'm new to drupal I have no idea whatsover, how to 'debug' or find a problem so any hint would be appreciated.

I created a new product display content type and then a new product of this type.
This new item shows up in the category list but not in the product list.

Repeatable : Always
Steps to reproduce :

```
install KC without demo store, no option selected
create a new content type : structure/content type/add new content type
save it : save and edit fields
add a product reference to this content type: add existing field / select product reference
save (this generate an error, I raised issue about it).
save settings
add a product category to this content type
save settings
save content type
Create a product : store/product/add product/
select the later display
fill the name, sky and price
save product
select a product category
save (bottom of the page) Now the product and its display should be created
click on the corresponding category on the main menu (top right) => the new item is listed
clik on all product (main menu) => the new item is not listed.
```

Is it a bug or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer. My new product wasn't displayed not because it was filtered but because the indexes used by the search API hasn't been updated. Seems obvious once you know that the view is not using  a query but the result of search.